# Unable to restart Redmine Server after installing plugin

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins, bitnami

I have installed Redmine server from Bitnami, version 1.3.2. I'm trying to install the latest XLS Export plugin from Redmine's website. I'm following the steps of Remove plugin folder, put the plugin in the folder, run rake, then restart the server. My issue is when I restart the Redmine server it doesn't come back online.

Here's a copy of the log from Redmine. When I was looking at it, I didn't see anything why the server wouldn't restart

```
    ** Daemonized, any open files are closed.  Look at tmp/pids/mongrel.3001.pid and    log/mongrel.3001.log for info.
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:3001
** Starting Rails with production environment...
** Mounting Rails at /redmine...
** Rails loaded.
** Loading any Rails specific GemPlugins
** Signals ready.  TERM => stop.  USR2 => restart.  INT => stop (no restart).
** Rails signals registered.  HUP => reload (without restart).  It might not work well.
** Mongrel 1.1.5 available at 0.0.0.0:3001
** Writing PID file to tmp/pids/mongrel.3001.pid
sh: darcs: command not found
sh: hg: command not found
sh: bzr: command not found
** TERM signal received.
** Daemonized, any open files are closed.  Look at tmp/pids/mongrel.3001.pid and  log/mongrel.3001.log for info.
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:3001
** Starting Rails with production environment...
** Mounting Rails at /redmine...
/Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport- 2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant': Object is not missing constant User! (ArgumentError)
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `const_missing'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:118:in `const_missing'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:124:in `send'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:124:in `const_missing'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/apps/redmine/app/models/project.rb:30
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require_or_load'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:451:in `load_missing_constant'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `const_missing'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:118:in `const_missing'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:463:in `load_missing_constant'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:122:in `const_missing'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/apps/redmine/app/models/query.rb:137
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/apps/redmine/vendor/plugins/redmine_xls_export/lib/xls_export.rb:2
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/apps/redmine/vendor/plugins/redmine_xls_export/init.rb:5:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:165:in `process'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/apps/redmine/config/environment.rb:24
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:147:in `rails'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:113:in `cloaker_'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `call'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `listener'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:99:in `cloaker_'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `call'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `initialize'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `new'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `run'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
from /Applications/redmine-1.3.2-1/ruby/bin/mongrel_rails:19
```

Answer (score 1):

(sudo) gem install spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have install spreadsheet gem successfully.

```
gem list | grep spreadsheet
```

If not installed then install it.

```
(sudo) gem install spreadsheet
```